# jQuery Create and Append Element

Tags: jquery

Its been a while since I have used jquery but I am not sure why I am having to do the following. I am creating a list item and appending it to a list.

```
    let userInput = $("#input").val();
    let listEntry = $('<li>', {
        text: userInput
    });
    listSafe.append(listEntry[0]);
```

When I am appending `listEntry` I am only getting `[object Object]` **unless** I use `[0]`. I could be wrong but in the past I don't believe I needed the `[0]` and I could just use `listSafe.append(listEntry);`

It would seem my issue is because I was using the vanilla javascript way of selecting an element

```
listSafe = document.getElementById("list-safe");
```

This caused the issue I was experiencing so changing to...

```
listSafe = $("#list-safe");
```

...solved my issue

Perhaps someone can explain why you cannot use the method I was attempting.

Comment: Your code works for me, if the input has a value, it gets inserted as a `<li>`

Answer (score 0):

Since your variable userInput is not array, you don't need to use [0].

Answer (score 0):

Your script will also work without using `[0]`, as jQuery `append()` will also accept a jQuery object as an argument, see here: [jQuery.append](https://api.jquery.com/append/#append-content-content).

```js
const listSafe=$("ul:first");
$("button:first").click(function(){
  let userInput = $("#input").val();
  let listEntry = $('<li>', {
    text: userInput
  });    
  listSafe.append(listEntry);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="input" value="something">
<button>add</button>
<ul><li>initial entry</li></ul>
```

**Update**

After I posted my answer here, OP changed his question again. So, the question now is "Why is it important how you create the contents of variable `listSafe`?"

Well, it is *all important*! When you use the jQuery way you obtain a *jQuery object* as a result. Using the vanilla JavaScript expression will result in a *DOM element*. *Both* objects will offer an `.append()` method, but these methods are *different*: The jQuery `.append()` is much more versatile (see my link above), as it will accept different types of arguments (HTML markup string, DOM element, jQuery object) while the DOM element's `.append()` expects a single DOM element *only*, see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild).

So, quintessentially: whenever you use jQuery, simply use it *all the way*, and things become so much easier!